# convert one factor column to multiple dichotomous columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, converters

I have a dataset with PatientID and their diagnoses, and they are as follows :

```
Id  Diagnoses
1   Nerve conditions (e.g., Multiple sclerosis, myasthenia gravis, Guillain-Barre syndrome, demyelinating polyneuropathy)
2   Gastrointestinal conditions (e.g., irritable bowl disease, ulcerative colitis, Chron's disease),Heart conditions,High blood pressure,Migraines/headaches
3   Heart conditions,Traumatic brain injury
4   Chronic pain,Heart conditions,Post-traumatic Stress Disorder (PTSD),Traumatic brain injury
5   Anxiety,Chronic pain,Depression,Sleep apnea
6   High blood pressure
7   High blood pressure
```

How can I split the `Diagnoses` column as follows :

```
Id  Anxiety       Depression      Nerve conditions  Sleep apnea Chronic Diseases  AND SO ON....
1   0               0              0                 1            1                
2   1               1              1                 1            1             
3   1               1              1                 1            0
4   0               0              1                 1            1          
5   1               0              0                 0            1         
6   1               1              1                 0            1         
7   1               1              0                 1            0
```

I have tried this code, but I did not get the result:

```
df %>%
   separate_rows(Diagnoses, sep=",") %>% 
   separate(Q2.3, into = c("Anxiety", "Depression, "THE REST OF CONDITIONS"), sep=":\\s*") %>% 
   mutate(anxiety1 = str_c("Anxiety", Anxiety))
```

I appreciate your help.,

Comment: How does `High blood pressure` gives 1 for `Anxiety` and `Depression` ? Why row 6 and 7 have 1 at different places when their value in `Diagnoses` is the same.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This was an example and it was not accurate. I just want to show you guys. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(Diagnoses = str_remove(Diagnoses, ' \\(.*\\)?')) %>% 
separate_rows(Diagnoses, sep = ',') %>% count(Id, Diagnoses, name = 'Cnt') %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = Id, names_from = Diagnoses, values_from = Cnt, values_fill = list(Cnt = 0))
# A tibble: 7 x 11
     Id `Nerve condition~ `Gastrointestina~ `Heart conditio~ `Traumatic brai~ `Chronic pain` `Post-traumatic ~ Anxiety Depression `Sleep apnea` `High blood pre~
  <dbl>             <int>             <int>            <int>            <int>          <int>             <int>   <int>      <int>         <int>            <int>
1     1                 1                 0                0                0              0                 0       0          0             0                0
2     2                 0                 1                0                0              0                 0       0          0             0                0
3     3                 0                 0                1                1              0                 0       0          0             0                0
4     4                 0                 0                1                0              1                 1       0          0             0                0
5     5                 0                 0                0                0              1                 0       1          1             1                0
6     6                 0                 0                0                0              0                 0       0          0             0                1
7     7                 0                 0                0                0              0                 0       0          0             0                1
>
```